# WPF Code-behind DataBinding Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Why is this code-behind DataBinding not working, when I do the same thing in XAML it is working fine.

```
 Binding frameBinding = new Binding();
 frameBinding.Source = mainWindowViewModel.PageName;
 frameBinding.Converter = this; // of type IValueConverter
 frameBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
 frameBinding.IsAsync = true;
 frame.SetBinding(Frame.ContentProperty, frameBinding);
```

Comment: Binding is successful. When the PageName property is set, the Property changed notification is also invoked. But after that it is not getting updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have only set the `Source` of the Binding, but not its `Path`. The declaration should look like this, using the `mainWindowViewModel` instance as `Source`:

```
Binding frameBinding = new Binding();
frameBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("PageName"); // here
frameBinding.Source = mainWindowViewModel; // and here
frameBinding.Converter = this;
frameBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
frameBinding.IsAsync = true;
frame.SetBinding(Frame.ContentProperty, frameBinding);
```

or shorter:

```
Binding frameBinding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("PageName"),
    Source = mainWindowViewModel,
    Converter = this,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
    IsAsync = true
};
frame.SetBinding(Frame.ContentProperty, frameBinding);
```

Comment: This is also **not** working: 
frameBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(".");
frameBinding.Source = mainWindowViewModel.PageName;